# Why use if-else rather than ternary operation in std::max implementation

Tags: c++, stl

In the implementation of std::max of in Ubuntu, I am confused as to why they use an `if` statement rather than the ternary operation. The ternary operation is in the comment (so it looks like it once was that way and was changed).  Any specify reason to use `if-else` here?

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline const _Tp&
max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
{
  // concept requirements
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_LessThanComparableConcept<_Tp>)
  //return  __a < __b ? __b : __a;
  if (__a < __b)
    return __b;
  return __a;
}
```

Comment: There's no specific reason to use `?:` rather than `if`/`else`. It's unlikely to matter one way or the other. Making the comment inconsistent with the code is admittedly a little jarring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I daresay that, "when the compiler's object-code generator gets through with *either* human-syntax alternative," it will make no difference whatsoever.

During the ordinary process of "compilation," 'your intentions' will be reduced to a series of primitive operations which will then be translated *(after optimization ...)* into executable code.   If, as in this case, "there are several ways to say it in source-code," they will most-likely be reduced to only one.